# iOS bring up WiFi authentication sheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, wifi

I'm having a problem with my iPad app not bringing up the WiFi authentication when it tries to access the network. When I first open the app and need to connect the panel will show, however if I lock the iPad and come back to it after the WiFi login session has timed out, the panel doesn't display.

Is this something I need to be coding for? My understanding was the panel came up automatically whenever you tried to use the network.

Comment: Sounds like a crappily configured hot spot. Have you tried testing against a different WiFi network?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with my hotspot... I think it has to do with some stuff (specific local domains) being allowed to work unauthenticated... not really sure, but the problem affects the entire system not just my app. I've decided to just go with "make the users aware and hope they complain to the right people" to get it fixed ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can code for it. Probably the user needs to toggle the wifi connection (switch it off and on) to get iOS to reconnect.

Comment: I was looking at CaptiveNetwork but it seems to only allow overriding the authentication and doesn't provide a way to tell the system that network operations are failing.